# How to get a list of files modified since date/revision in Accurev

Tags: accurev

I have created a workspace backed by some collaboration stream. The stream is updated regularly by team members. My goal is to take modified files in a given path and put them to another repository (do it regularly).

The question is how to create a list of files which were modified since a revision or date or ..? (I don't know which approach is the best.) The command line is preferable.

Once I get the file list I create an automating script to take the files from one place and put them to another.

Answer (score 2):

accurev hist -s Your_Stream -t "2013/05/16 01:00:00"-now -a -fl

Answer (score 1):

You can run `accurev stat -m -fx` and then parse resulting XML. `element` elements will have `modTime` attribute, which is the UNIX timestamp when the file was modified.

Comment: This won't work. This command will display files that have been modified and not yet promoted.